# Error in selection after sorting dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting, drop-down-menu

I have sorted a dropdown list with this function:

```
function SortOptions(id) {
    var prePrepend = "#";
    if (id.match("^#") == "#") prePrepend = "";
    $(prePrepend + id).html($(prePrepend + id + " option").sort(
        function (a, b) { return a.text == b.text ? 0 : a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1 })
    );  
}
```

But when i'm selecting a object i get the item with the index from before sorting.

The selection is happening with this function:

```
var selectedType = typeDropdown.selectedItemData();

selectedItemData: function (index) {
    var settings = this.data(extensionName);
    if (typeof (index) === 'undefined') {
        return settings._items ? settings._items[this[0].selectedIndex] || null : null;
    } else {
        this[0].selectedIndex = index;
        this.selectmenu('refresh');
    }
}
```

Is this enough information?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not the problem, but FWIW, I'd pass the regular expression to `match` as a regular expression rather than as a string: `id.match(/^#/)`. Also note that you're relying on `==` to convert the resulting match to a string (`["#"]` into `"#"`). It *works*, but...

Comment: For that matter, `id.charAt(0) == "#"` would be a lot clearer, probably faster too...

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I have found that my problem i in this line:

settings._items ? settings._items[this[0].selectedIndex]

_items is the unsorted and this[0] is sorted and there for it's a wrong match.